# How to print sum of 2 numbers in MIPS?

Tags: mips

I am trying to get the sum of 2 numbers but facing difficulties. I did tried to store values in v0 and tried to add them using s0. But it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0):

#below is an example

.data
int1 : .word 23

int2 : .word 3

result : .word 0

.globl main

.text

main:

lw $t0, int1

lw $t1, int2

add $t2,$t0,$t1

sw $t2, result

li $v0, 1  #these instructions will be used to print

lw $a0, result

syscall

Answer (score 0):

```
.data
A: .word 2 # this is the block to initialize values 
B: .word 4

.text

.globl  main
.ent    main
main:
    lw $t0,A # load value of A in temp register t0 
    lw $t1,B # load value of B in temp register t1
    add $t2,$t0,$t1 # add the value of temp register t0 and t1 then place it in temp register t2
    
    li $v0,10 #
    syscall   # exit the program
.end    main
```